# Send SOAP service reponse without client requst in Axis2

Tags: web-services, soap, apache-axis

I want to send response(I am getting the data from my DB) continuously every 5 minutes without any request from client by using SOAP and Axis2. I have created the SOAP server by using following link. http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/TopDownAxis2WebService/td_tutorial.html

But I don't know how to response continuously from server. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A webservice cannot send a response without being called because it won't know where to send the data nor what function is being invoked (a ws could have many functions).

The idea of a WS is to offer a service to everyone who can access it, so the response destinies are multiple.

If you want to get the data from your DB every 5 minutes, your client will have to call the WS every 5 minutes or less (take into account the server processing time).